# save the text on coreData

Tags: cocoa, core-data

I am new iphone development. In my app, i am using two textfield and i want to save the text on the dada base which is entered in textfield then i want to display it. Here i am using CoreData base. I am feeling difficult to understand all classes on the coreData base. Here i am created view based application. What are the classes required to achieve that and is there any sample and idea?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to save two `NSString`s, you should use a simpler storage method, like `NSUserDefaults`, instead of Core Data, which is to be used for storing larger quantities of data. You can easily save an object to `NSUserDefaults` by using this code:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:someString forKey:@"someKey"];
```

Then you can retrieve the saved object like this:

```
NSString *someString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"someKey"];
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but here, i should be use only core data because it is required.

Comment: Why are you required to use Core Data to do this? For saving just two strings, using Core Data is overkill...

Comment: Because, I want to save large number of data in future, so that i am asking coreData. but NSUserDefaults is enough as consider two textfield string.